# Sort multiple csv files within a directory by date python

Tags: python, csv, date, sorting

I have **multiple** `.csv` files in the same directory called **Original** and I want to sort all these files per date, descending (the oldest first) - second column. Every file should be sorted and overwrite the original file. Is it possible? If not, then saved in another directory called **Sorted**. Can somebody help me?

Original csv

```
ORA.PA,13/04/2021,10.35,10.35,10.14,10.21,4299528
ORA.PA,27/02/2019,13.36,13.48,13.29,13.3,6929606
ORA.PA,26/02/2019,13.46,13.52,13.35,13.4,6031759
ORA.PA,05/11/2018,13.94,14.21,13.9,14.16,7692439
ORA.PA,02/11/2018,14.1,14.1,13.9,13.96,6867565
ORA.PA,15/04/2011,7.84,7.89,7.7,7.75,8277622
ORA.PA,14/08/2001,20.22,20.22,19.74,19.85,9221300
```

The desired Output

```
ORA.PA,14/08/2001,20.22,20.22,19.74,19.85,9221300
ORA.PA,15/04/2011,7.84,7.89,7.7,7.75,8277622
ORA.PA,02/11/2018,14.1,14.1,13.9,13.96,6867565
ORA.PA,05/11/2018,13.94,14.21,13.9,14.16,7692439
ORA.PA,26/02/2019,13.46,13.52,13.35,13.4,6031759
ORA.PA,27/02/2019,13.36,13.48,13.29,13.3,6929606
ORA.PA,13/04/2021,10.35,10.35,10.14,10.21,4299528
```

This is the code that I used and didn't work, I am getting nothing

```
import csv
import operator
import glob

data = dict() 

path="/Original/*.csv"
files=glob.glob(path)

for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lists = [row for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')]
        data[filename] = sorted(lists, operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use salutations: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. Mainly you are only reading from the file; not writing to it. You would need to open the file with the 'r+' option in order to be able to write to the file as well as reading it. Additionally the sorting won't work that way, as the dates have the format dd/mm/yyyy. For sorting they should be reversed, so yyyy-mm-dd. I also changed the inline data reading from your code to an actual for loop, as the inline solution didn't work, though I don't know why that is...

All in all the following code should solve your problems, please let me know if it works...

```
import csv
import operator
import glob

path="./Original/*.csv"
files=glob.glob(path)

for filename in files:
    with open(filename, "r+", newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        lists = []
        for row in reader:
            lists.append(row)

        # Reverses the date for sorting, so that they are sorted correctly        
        lists.sort(key=lambda a:'-'.join(a[1].split('/')[::-1]))

        # deletes content of the file
        f.truncate(0)
        f.seek(0)

        # writes the new data to the file
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(lists)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly. And thanks for the commentary, they help me to learn!